# Struggling to Derive Particle Flux Expression - Help

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, particle-detectors

Hiii, im trying to derive a result of a paper i having problem.
I have a flux of particles described by the equation: $Φ=Φ_0cos⁡²(θ)$, where $\theta$ represents the zenith angle. In addition, I have a tank with a radius RR, and I can assume that the lid area is much larger than the lateral area of the tank.

My goal is to calculate dn(θ) at the top and bottom of the tank over a period T. The expected result is given by:

$$dn(θ)=2π²R²TΦ_0cos⁡³(θ)sin⁡(θ)dθ$$

I've attempted various approaches to derive this result, but I've been unable to obtain it. It's possible that I'm missing a factor of R, π, or struggling to properly account for the cosine and sine terms.

Any help would be awesome, i think its not a hard problem, but im just not getting it.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SE. Please provide a diagram with annotation of all the symbols. Also, can you please provide more details on what you have tried and where you got stuck